# Memory Profiler - Advanced Profiling Unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-profiling

I am running app on Api 26, Android 8.0.0 Huawei Mate 10 Pro. 
I can use advanced profiling with emulator but not with real device. 
The error is: Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you select a "Debug" build variant, and not a "Release" build type.